# GeometricScene revisited

Tags: geometry

Studying a new command `GeometricScene`, I try

```
GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, 
e -> {1/2, 1}}, {Triangle[{a, e, d}], Triangle[{a, b, d}], 
Line[a, e], Line[d, b], Point[{x, y}] \[Element] Line[a, e], 
Point[{x, y}] \[Element] Line[d, b]}]
```

Then I want to find the numbers `x` and `y`. Here are my unsuccessful attempts:

```
%["Conclusions"]
```

> `{}`

```
%%["Points"]
```

> `{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, e -> {1/2, 1}}`

```
RandomInstance[GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, c -> {1, 1}, d -> {0, 1}, 
e -> {1/2, 1}}, {Triangle[{a, e, d}], Triangle[{a, b, d}], 
Line[a, e], Line[d, b], Point[{x, y}] \[Element] Line[a, e], 
Point[{x, y}] \[Element] Line[d, b]}]];
Replace[{x, y}, %["Quantities"]]
```

> `{x, y}`

Could that be done within `GeometricScene`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm removing `c` and the triangles for clarity. Points within `Line` should be enclosed in braces, and you should add a named point for your sought after intersection:

```
gs = GeometricScene[
  {
    a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0},
    d -> {0, 1}, e -> {1/2, 1},
    p
  },
  {
    Line[{a, e}], Line[{d, b}], 
    p ∈ Line[{a, e}], 
    p ∈ Line[{d, b}]
  }
];

inst = RandomInstance[gs]
```

[image: a diagram of the geometric scene]

```
inst["Points"]

(* Out: 
{a -> {0., 0.},  
 b -> {1., 0.},
 d -> {0., 1.},
 e -> {0.5, 1.},
 p -> {0.333333, 0.666666} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for some progress. First, comma before `p` in line 4 of your code is omitted. Second, the approximate result `{a -> {0., 0.}, b -> {1., 0.}, d -> {0., 1.}, e -> {0.5, 1.}, 
 p -> {0.333333, 0.666666}}`  could not be called satisfactory for this simple geometric task. Third, the code with the triangles `gs = GeometricScene[{a -> {0, 0}, b -> {1, 0}, d -> {0, 1}, 
    e -> {1/2, 1}, p}, {Line[{a, e}], Line[{d, b}], 
    p \[Element] Line[{a, e}], p \[Element] Line[{d, b}], 
    Triangle[{a, e, d}], Triangle[{a, b, d}]}];
inst = RandomInstance[gs]` returns the input.

Comment: I'd like to add the triangles are needed for some purpose.

Comment: @user64494 Thank you for pointing out the missing comma; I fixed that. As far as I know, the methods used by `GeometricScene` are numerical, so a symbolic output is not available (yet, perhaps). See [this comment from Chip Hurst](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200464/symbolic-formula-from-geometricscene#comment518646_200464) on the topic.

Comment: @user64494 To your second point about the expression with the triangles returning the input, that's not what I see: https://imgur.com/a/UYZsjQC. I am on version 12.0 on Win10-64.

Comment: For the user's convenience, I 'd like to qoute "@Chip Hurst ah okay, that's a little disappointing but maybe it's something the developers are working on. At the very least it'd be nice to get some kind of numeric function object out of GeometricScene for things like this so that passing it to one of the optimization functions could be easier/more efficient. – 
ccosm
 Jun 16 '19 at 23:04
seems like a good idea. I’ll pass this along to the development team".

Comment: MarcoB (@does not work.) :[That](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1groy2yvxrujga/%D0%97%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BA%20%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%202021-12-15%2017.58.42.png?dl=0) I see on my comp.

Comment: @user64494 Yes, but then you have to ask for a `RandomInstance` of the `GeometricScene` to see an actual realization of it, as the code in my screenshot showed. `GeometricScene` does try to represent the scene if it can, but it doesn't always return a `Graphics` object.

Comment: MarcoB: Concerning "a symbolic output ", I  see nothing symbolic (i.e. symbolic parameters) in your code.